# Using string.execute() in Windows Jenkins slave run on master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, execute, master-slave

I am trying to use the `String.execute()` under the scope `node('node_name)`, in  a Jenkinsfile that runs on a Windows Jenkins slave.

After some issues, i discovered that this specific method runs on my Jenkins master (linux), not on the slave.

There is a reason for that?

Is there a way to use that method and it will run on the slave?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Jenkinsfile needs to include `agent { <labelname served by slave>}` either immediately below `pipeline {` or in the particular `stage`.

DSL for the agent keyword is only currently supported in these two possible locations.

Comment: Thanks. but if you look at this page: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds, you can see that even on this options you suggested, the Jenkinsfile run form the master, and then send requests to the slave. For some reason, the String.execute() doesn't work like it.